# How to override an existing node_module interface property

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a custom type declaration file, in which I would like to override an already existing interface property (not **create** a new property, but modify existing)

I have tried several approaches, such as Omiting the property (shown below), with no luck.

```
src/types/example.d.ts
----------


import package, { AnInterface } from 'example'

interface CustomInstance extends Omit<Instance, 'clients'> {
  clients: string[];
}

declare module "example-module" {
  export interface Instance extends CustomInstance {
    test: number
    clients: CustomType
  }
}


src/main.ts
-----------


example.test // number as expected 
example.clients // is always the type from node_modules, not my .d.ts file
```

If I try to add `clients` without doing any extending, I get`Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'clients' must be of type 'EDictionary', but here has type 'CustomType'`

however if I try to extend the custom instance (as above) I get the error `Type 'Instance' recursively references itself as a base type.` (which even if I `ts-ignore`, my application will still use the type defined in node_modules).

Comment: You cannot. Declaration merging only supports adding properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can't *un-define* something with d.ts, you can only define it more precisely.

Best you can to remove something is re-export everything from your module, changing its types

In your case you may want to not un-define `clients` but to narrow it down, then that will be

```
import { EDictionary } from 'example-module';

declare module "example-module" {
  export interface Instance { // i.e. extends example-module.Instance
    test: number
    clients: CustomType & EDictionary // narrow it down in a compatible manner
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this could work. Unfortunately example-module doesn't export EDictionary which makes things fun... Guess I'll copy the definition in, and go the route of using an intersection as suggested.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I still get `Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'clients' must be of type 'EDictionary', but here has type 'EDictionary & Extension'.` when trying `clients: EDictionary & Extension;` where Extension re-defines one of the interface properties as I require.